# Trying to find out the average length of employment for all employees

Tags: sql, oracle

And round it to the nearest year.

```
select employee_id, months_between(start_date, sysdate) 
from job_history;
```

So far I've been able to calculate the number of months.

I am working with 12c

Comment: Is there an end date field in the job_history table?

Comment: Yes there is an end date field

Comment: If that's the case, you want to use the end_date instead of the sysdate

Comment: In that case, what does "all employees" mean? Active as well as terminated employees? Or only the ones who are currently active? Also, is it possible that an employee worked there from 2003 to 2010, then they left, but returned in 2015? Then perhaps those two periods should be combined together? It is always best to ask and answer these questions before going to writing code.

Comment: Its only for employees who have been with the company and also have a defined termination date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the average, then you need aggregation:

```
select avg(months_between(sysdate, start_date) ) as avg_months
from job_history;
```

If you want it in years:

```
select round(avg(months_between(sysdate, start_date))/12) as avg_years
from job_history;
```

Comment: select job_id, round(avg(months_between(start_date, end_date))) as avg_years
from job_history
group by job_id; Thanks was able to get it to work with just a few tweaks!

Comment: @BrandonW - `avg_years` without dividing by 12 anywhere? Are you sure? And the `months_between` as Gordon wrote it will produce negative numbers. I edited his post to correct both issues, but I see you marked it "Correct" without those fixes. Did you test it before you marked it "Correct"?

Comment: Your correct mathguy I'm still new to SQL.  This time it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it would look like

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(year,start_date, end_date)) AS AverageLengthOfEmployment from job_history
```

Comment: DATEDIFF? Not aware of that existing in Oracle. Are you suspecting the OP mis-tagged the question?

Comment: Sorry. It was tagged as just sql when I answered

Comment: I just checked the edits and I see that. I should do that more often, before I ask questions like the one I asked - "Sorry" from me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  employee_id
, AVG(CAST( months_between(start_date, sysdate) / 12 AS INTEGER) AS avg_work_years
FROM job_history
```

Comment: You cast "months/12" as integer, and THEN take the average? That makes no sense. Take the average and divide by 12 (or divide by 12 and take the average), and only the cast as integer. (In Oracle that is done with the ROUND() function.)

Comment: Hi mathguy. It depends on the type of query. Usually you want to express how many years someone has been working somewhere; and then you take the average; insurance companies calculate duration of employment  - and age of insured person, for that matter, that way. Depends on the business case, though, you're right in that. And ROUND() exists in almost every database, but it's much slower, as it's a floating point operation. A hard CAST() is an INTEGER operation and faster by orders of magnitude. Some DBs FLOOR() in case of CAST() instead of ROUND() - ing. In that case, add 6 months beforehand.

Comment: I learned (to my huge disappointment) that Oracle doesn't do ANY integer arithmetic in ANYTHING.  :-(